# Hbase web application using java

Tags: java, hbase

I'm trying to develop a web application using java and I just want use HBase as my back end database. 
I'm able use the HBase Java API but the problem is with the Web Application, I'm trying to write the HBase Java API code in JSPs(java server pages), is this the right way for developing HBase Web Application ???

I'm not having any idea of developing HBase web application. Please help me to find out procedure or any sample examples so that I can try it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is off-topic - please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I Develop a Hbase Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491212/how-can-i-develop-a-hbase-web-application)